# Use image gallery and main text in Product

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

This is an example of JSON-LD for a Schema.org `Product`:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Executive Anvil",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.4",
    "ratingCount": "89"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "119.99",
    "highPrice": "199.99",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
</script>
```

But I have a lot of more properties for my product.

For example a related gallery, related videos, a long main text.
There are not these properties in Product.

Do I have to leave them? Or is there a way to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For content about the product (like a video, a gallery, an article, etc.) you could use the `Product` item as value of the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "Video about your product",
  "about": {
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Your product"
  }
}
```

With JSON-LD’s `@reverse`, you can specify these within the `Product` item, if you prefer it:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Your product",
  "@reverse": {
    "about": {
      "@type": "VideoObject",
      "name": "Video about your product"
    }
  }
}
```